# Django class based views access passed arguments

Tags: django, django-views

How can I log / print passed values to class based view?

Here is my class

```
class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
```

I have tried appending the following to the class but I'm not seeing anything printed in the console.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    logging.info(request['name'])
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `self.args` and `self.kwargs` works in any generic class-based-view.

```
class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        project_name = self.kwargs.get('project_name', None)
        # Do something 
        return super(ProjectUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Looking at [Classy Class Based Views](https://ccbv.co.uk/), a great site for viewing the methods and attributes standard CBVs, shows us why this is. Take a look at this from the [TemplateView source code](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/):

```
@classonlymethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    """
    Main entry point for a request-response process.
    """
    # sanitize keyword arguments
    for key in initkwargs:
        if key in cls.http_method_names:
            raise TypeError("You tried to pass in the %s method name as a "
                            "keyword argument to %s(). Don't do that."
                            % (key, cls.__name__))
        if not hasattr(cls, key):
            raise TypeError("%s() received an invalid keyword %r. as_view "
                            "only accepts arguments that are already "
                            "attributes of the class." % (cls.__name__, key))
    def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        self = cls(**initkwargs)
        if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
            self.head = self.get
        self.request = request
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The unpacked args and kwargs passed to the `view` method are stored as class attributes and available at any post-initialization methods.